# How to upload multiple images with DropzoneJS

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I don't really understand properly the concept behind uploading multiple files with preview. I checked DropzoneJS and it looks nice and I feel I can do a lot of stuff with it.

I have this example: I have a user (id: 801) that creates a new post (id: TBD since the post is not yet created). I have a table `image_post` which holds the images of the specific post, and an `image` table which holds the image details. Now, I have the Dropzone form which is supposed to upload images to a folder that I specify in the .php file that is implemented to deal with the ajax request coming from Dropzone. Let's say the user uploads 2 images and I store them into an `temp` folder. The user submits the creating of the new post, it receives an ID: 10001. The temporary files are on the disk (but should they be stored in the DB as well?) but don't see how to link the post to the images.

What are the exact steps that are required to be able to (after the files were uploaded with Dropzone ajax request) link those images to the actual post id?

Answer (score 0):

Your system will need to create a database record for the post prior to them uploading images. Consider the following table structure, where an *i* prefix indicates an INT column, *s* a VARCHAR/TEXT column, and *dt* a DATETIME.

Table `posts`: `iPostId | iUserId | iStatus | sComments | dtCreated`

Table `photos`: `iPhotoId | iPostId | dtUploaded`

When a user begins to start a new post, create a record in the posts table with their user id, an empty comments, a datetime such as '0000-00-00 00:00:00', and a status of *0*, and then add a hidden form input to the photo upload form so that the assigned post id is known to your photo upload script, e.g.:

`<input type="hidden" name="iPostId" value="22" />`

The photo upload script could create a new record in the photos table using the post id and then save the photo in a particular folder using the post id in the filename, for example if the photo_id for the record created was 2821 you would save the file as 2821.jpg in your chosen folder.

When the user finishes their post and clicks to save/submit, you could use an UPDATE query to modify the original record on the posts table, assigning their entered text to the sComments column, the current date and time to the dtCreated column, and changing the iStatus to 1.

On your pages where you display a list of posts simply modify your query to something like this to exclude those currently in a draft status (0): `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status=1;`, and then when viewing the post you can run a query such as `SELECT * FROM photos WHERE post_id=22;` to get an array of the photos to be displayed.

Obviously this can be expanded upon but hopefully gives you a good starting point.